# Drinking Straw physics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

I was just wondering, when you put a straw in water and block the top, water doesn't get out from the bottom when you lift it up.

What about alcohol like Vodka ( ethanol )? I am trying to make a straw such that when you block the top, the alcohol actually does get out from the bottom. I just have no clue what diameter, shape, or modifications I should make into the straw in order to achieve this.

As i know the surface tension of Ethanol is 22.1 mN/m

Answer (score 0):

The lower the surface tension of the fluid, the smaller you have to make the opening on the end of the straw. Because this sort of behavior is so sensitively dependent on the cleanliness of the surfaces and the purity of the liquid in contact with them, it is best to determine the optimum diameter by experiment.